# How to take user input and store it as a LAN for a network ping test?

Tags: python, networking, concatenation, ping

I'm a network engineer for a couple thousand medical facilities and they have a homogenous LAN setup, so .15 will always be the 'time clock', x.x.x.27 will always be the main printer, etc.

I want to make a script that has those 'constants' stored already, and takes the user input (the relative LAN for that facility), and adds each 'constant' to the end of it, then takes those IPs and pings each of them, returning the results.

This is my first project and I'm excited at the utility to streamline my work efficiency. Here is a recent attempt:

```
x = (input("Enter a LAN minus the last octet: "))

for i in range(1, 255):
    if i == 1 or 2 or 10 or 15 or 27: 
        f = open("IPS.txt")
        f.write(str(x) + str(i))
```

I'm not sure if this is the right start, I've iterated my attempts a few times but that's my current wall, actually facilitating this within the python code.

Comment: The expression `if i == 1 or 2 or 10 or 15 or 27: ` does not do what you think it does. You want either `if i == 1 or i == 2 or i == 10 or i == 15 or i == 27:`, or more compactly `if i in [1, 2, 10, 15, 27]:`

Comment: Very nice, I will be putting this into use. Thank you.